# git squash changes for one file

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, undo

I have several commits that do ineffective changes to a file but some of them are combined with relevant changes to another file. So I would like to just squash the changes to the one file. How can I do that?

Example:
The following should symbolize the commits and the `[......]` the content of the file.

This is what I have:

- commit 5  `file A: [.....] file B: [......]`
- commit 4  `file A: [     ] file B: [....  ]`
- commit 3  `file A: [.....] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 2  `file A: [     ] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 1  `file A: [.....] file B: [..    ]`

The diff would be:

- commit 5  `file A: [+++++] file B: [....++]`
- commit 4  `file A: [-----] file B: [...+  ]`
- commit 3  `file A: [+++++] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 2  `file A: [-----] file B: [..+   ]`
- commit 1  `file A: [+++++] file B: [++    ]`

In this case file A at commits 5, 3 and 1 is the same.

This is what I want:
So I would like to squash it to have.

- commit 5  `file A: [.....] file B: [......]`
- commit 4  `file A: [.....] file B: [....  ]`
- commit 2  `file A: [.....] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 1  `file A: [.....] file B: [..    ]`

The diff would be:

- commit 5  `file A: [.....] file B: [....++]`
- commit 4  `file A: [.....] file B: [...+  ]`
- commit 2  `file A: [.....] file B: [..+   ]`
- commit 1  `file A: [+++++] file B: [..    ]`

Is there any way to do that.

**Edit:** Maybe I was not very clear in my question. I know how to do interactive rebasing and squash in general. It is more about the fact, that I want to only "squash" the ineffective changes of file A, while I preserve the changes on file B. (Doing this would result in commit 3 doing nothing, and thus it is removed.)

The problem I'm facing with "normal" rebasing would be, if I just squash all commits from 1-5, I would end up with the result I want for file A, but all intermediate changes to file B are lost.

I have added a representation of diff to maybe better depict the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be multiple interactive rebases. To sum up, you should **edit** `commit 4` and `commit 5` while interactive rebasing. Let me explain:

You already found that squashing `commit 2` and `commit 3` is the first step. When we just do that, the beginning of the commit history will be like after first interactive rebase:

- commit 2  `file A: [.....] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 1  `file A: [.....] file B: [..    ]`

Well, let's analyze the scenario. Your `file B` changes will be kept, the same as `commit 4` and `commit 5`. However, we need to get rid of `file A` changes. This is where we will get help from **edit** option in interactive rebase.

While interactive rebasing, select **edit** option for `commit 4` and `commit 5`. While editing state for both commits, seperate file A changes from the commit. So a sample history will be look like after second interactive rebase:

```
1--2--4A--4B--5A--5B
```

that `4A` only includes changes in file `A` at `commit 4`. Then final rebase; move `5A` commit next to `4A` commit and squash two commits into `commit 2`. And magic, because they are opposite commits, they will be disappeared. And commit history will look like after third interactive rebase:

- commit 5B `file A: [.....] file B: [......]`
- commit 4B `file A: [.....] file B: [....  ]`
- commit 2   `file A: [.....] file B: [...   ]`
- commit 1   `file A: [.....] file B: [..    ]`

as you wanted.

Comment: This answer is confusing (and not very accurate) in how it describes the rebase, and it incorrectly suggests that multiple interactive rebases are needed.

Comment: To apply this solution, you need at least 2 interactive rebases. However, I prefer 3 rebase to take firm steps. It is not incorrect, it is a working style.

Comment: You keep saying that, so I double checked just to seei if something about the nature of the tool had changed; it has not, and I was again able to do it in 1.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done.  It is a history rewrite, which means if there is a remote it will involve force-pushing branches, and if that remote is shared with other users, then you need to coordinate with them first or you run the risk that they'll undo your changes when they try to recover from the errors they will encounter after you force push.  You can find more about the issues with force pushing to shared repos in the `git rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase".

---

So in small/simple cases like your example, you could use an interactive rebaes to do it.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

This will load a rebasing "TODO" list with commits 2, 3, 4, and 5.  (In your example you're not changing commit 1; if you need to change it, you could either use `HEAD~5` in the case where there's prior history, or the `--root` option in the case where there is not.)

Each line in the "TODO" list represents a commit, and starts with a command that tells rebase what to do with that commit.  On the line for commit 3, change the command from "pick" to "squash"; this will combine the changes from commits 2 and 3 into a single commit.  On the line for commit 4, change the command from "pick" to "edit".  Save and quit from the editor.

When the rebase is ready to rewrite commit 4, it will pause and let you apply changes before proceeding.  Pull the correct version of file A

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/file_A
git add .
```

then finish the rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```

You can get information about all the interactive rebase options from the rebase documentation page.  (There are also other ways to get the same effect in simple situations; but of the ways that are suitable for small/simple use cases, `rebase -i` is the most suited-for-the-purpose IMO.)

This procedure is somewhat manual, and it will run into problems for more complex histories that contain merges, or that are reachable from multiple branches (or tags, or other refs).  In those cases you could use `git filter-repo`.  This is a fairly sophisticated tool, so there is some learning curve.  But it does have decent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a fresh start with:

   ```
   git reset {commit 1 HASH}
   ```

   and redo the commits as you please.
2. Have new commit that undoes your previous commits

   ```
   git revert {commit 1 HASH}
   ```
3. Squash commits

   ```
   git rebase -i {commit 1 HASH}
   ```

Don’t worry if you are not very comfortable with git-rebase. Squashing
commit is a very simple technique to achieve with interactive
git-rebase The interactive rebase will open up the editor. And you can
see how `rebase -i` has taken the last three commits. And note the
number of options that it has. Let’s concentrate only on squash.
As
mentioned earlier, let’s make it to a single commit. You can see that we have marked the last two commits to squash. You can use *squash* or *s* to mark the commit to squash.

[Please continue following this tutorial on this page for squashing commits, it is very explanatory](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-squash-git-commits-9a095c1bc1fc)

I would recommend to go with option 1. and have a fresh start, but it is your choice.